# Troubleshooting 'i2c_hid_acpi i2c-: failed to set a report to device' Error in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, i2c, hid, acpi, chromium-os

Context:
I'm working on a Chromebook and encountered an issue with I2C communication. I have a specific I2C device that's causing the following error message to appear in the `dmesg` output after several minutes to sometimes hours of writing via hidraw0:

> i2c-: failed to set a report to device

Linux Distribution:

```ini
NAME=Chromium OS
ID=chromiumos
HOME_URL=https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os
BUG_REPORT_URL=https://crbug.com/new
VERSION=99
VERSION_ID=99
BUILD_ID=14462.0.2022_04_11_1828
```

Error Message:
I've provided the error message above.

Actions Taken:
I've checked the hardware connections, and they seem to be fine. I've also looked into the kernel drivers; the relevant driver is loaded.

Expectations:
I expected the I2C communication to work correctly without errors.

Attempts to Resolve:
I've searched online for information about this error message, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Specific Questions:
What could be the potential root causes of the 'failed to set a report to device' error in the context of HID-I2C communication?

Comment: In the subject you have `i2c_hid_acpi i2c-:` which looks like the device name is empty or mangled. After the dash it should be something like "PNP0000:01". Are you sure you have correct ACPI tables to begin with? ChromeOS doing many things in its own way (via CoreBoot), so the ACPI tables may not work correctly with other OSes.

Comment: @0andriy There is an ID PARA3406:00 I removed it because I didn't want to focus on the device attached.